# Phusion Passenger is crashing...how can I get a stack trace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I'm using Phusion Passenger 2.2.2 with a Rails 2.3.8 and 2.3.2 apps. Every once in awhile it will freeze and there is no response from the server when trying to access the rails applications. There is nothing in the apache log or the rails logs. I'm not talking about a 500 error or anything, there is just no response whatsoever. They don't respond until we restart apache.

I tried to follow these instructions to try to get a stack trace: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#debugging_frozen

I sent SIGABRT to the processes, according to the instructions, and they did not seem to care. Didn't see anything in the apache or rails logs.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on serverfault? You would get a better response there.

Comment: Okay, I will ask there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way to troubleshoot this problem on Passenger is to  issue a `kill -SIGABRT` to the stuck Rails processes, and find their backtrace in the `Rails log`